# Handling forms with multiple actions

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have an Admin page with a list of items, and I have various capabilities to modify those records -- Change its name, Delete it, Clear its contents, etc. For example a row would be rendered similar to the following:

```
const row =`<tr id="id${this.id}">
                <td name="name">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Set name" value=${this.name} />
                    <input type="submit" name="setName" value="Save" />
                </td>
                <td name="size">${this.set.size}<td/>
                <td name="elements"><b>{ ${this.renderSetElements()} }</td>
                <td name="actions">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Add element" />
                    <input type="submit" name="addElement" value="Add" />
                    <input type="submit" name="clearElements" value="Clear" />
                    <input type="submit" name="deleteSet" value="Delete" />
                </td>
           </tr>`
```

What would the proper way to add forms here? Should there be one form around the row? Should there be four forms per row -- one for each action? (setName, addElement, clearElements, deleteSet)? Or what is the suggested way to accomplish the above? Additionally, is identifying the row as `id${this.id}` appropriate, or what's usually the contention for something like that?

Comment: The `form` element needs to be inside the `td`, and definitely not outside it, that would break `table` conventions about having to nest `td` inside `tr`, and `tr` inside `tbody` or `table`. So the only way left is to have one form / action.

Comment: andrei -- what would be a better way to structure the above then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can have a

1. The `form` inside a cell `td`.

```html
<table>  
  <tr><td><form>...</form></td></tr>
  <tr><td><form>...</form></td></tr>
</table>
```

2. You can have a `table` inside a `form`

```html
<form>
  <table>  
    <tr><td>...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>...</td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

3. Or you can ditch the form element and use JavaScript to do Ajax:

*In this case, I will be using the Javascript library `jQuery` since it simplifies a lot of stuff; however, you can implement this with pure Javascript if you want to.*

```js
// Wait for the document to be fully loaded
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".submit").on("click", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("submit...");
      var url = "https://httpbin.org/get";
      var data = {
        id: $('#id').val()
      };
      $.get(url, data, function(result){ 
        console.log("Server received the id number: ", result.args.id); 
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>  
  <tr>
    <td><input class="inputs" id="id" value="0"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="submit" id="add">Add</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In your particular case, you might try generate these rows dynamically and using Ajax to send the information to the server, without having to refresh the whole page. Here is an example:

```js
(function(){

  let count = 0;

  function createColumn(){
    let column = $('<td>');
    let text = $(`<input type="text" placeholder="Set name" value="${count}">`);
    let submit = $('<button class="save" type="submit" name="setName">Save</button>');
    column.append(text);
    column.append(submit);
    return column;
  }

  function createRow(){
    let row = $('<tr>');
    row.attr("id", count++);
    row.append(createColumn());
    return row;
  }

  let table = $('#table');
  $('#btnAdd').on('click', () => {
    table.append(createRow());
  });

  table.on('click', '.save', function() {
    let text = $(this).prev().val();
    console.log("INPUT TEXT:", text);
  }); 

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnAdd">Add Row</button>
<table id="table">
</table>
```

I hope you found this informative, useful, and that you can apply it to your particular issue.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. What is `$('<td>');` ? Is that jQuery? And is `.append` a method that can be used on normal javascript or is that another jQuery method?

Comment: In these examples, I'm using the `jQuery` library which simplifies many things related with JavaScript. In this case, I can tell jQuery to create and return a `td` element. However, be aware that all these examples can be done with pure JavaScript too.